# SP that generates a SQL table from the clipboard

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, clipboard

Retrieving data from Excel to a SQL server database is common.

Let's say I have selected 4 columns of data from Excel and I copyed this data to my Clipboard.

**Q: How can I generate a table (temporary or normal) with 4 columns (could be all characters) ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thinking is fundamentally flawed.  Excel is a client application where the user interface *is* the application, whereas SQL **Server** is a server type application, where SQL management studio is provided as a facilitator, not inherent in the application itself.

It is concievably plausible that you could use a CLR stored procedure to access the clipboard but I would advise against it.

Comment: If there's a firm that wants to stop using Excel and move to a database app, they don't want to loose all there data.

Comment: Let's say that this firm has 200 clients, over 1000 products and so on. Your answer is that they have to re-enter all this data again ?

Comment: @Misi - If that's the situation then ask a question about your root need (how to import from excel) not your half baked solution involving the clipboard.

Comment: My question is **not** about Excel, is about data in rows and columns(data separated by tabs and carriage return) *dbf, *csv, could be a html <table />.